# Colorize output logs of a native command-line app in the PowerShell console

Tags: powershell, kubectl

I'm using `kubectl` to print logs from pods. (my adventure with kubectl and powershell started today)

Our logs always start with:

```
[12:00:49 INF] ...
or
[12:00:49 WRN] ...
or
[12:00:49 ERR] ...
```

My goal is to see those lines in colors based on log level.

I would assume I need to add some kind of script to `$profile` analyzing output of `kubectl` and colorize it line by line.

Please note that in `$profile` file I already have scripts for kubectl autocomplete.

Is it possible to do and if so could you please direct me how to do it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: the question is: How to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448439/7571258), here is something that you could put into your `$Profile` file to *automatically* colorize output of `kubectl`:

```sh
$KubectlStyle = @{ 
    INF = $PSStyle.Formatting.FormatAccent
    WRN = $PSStyle.Formatting.Warning
    ERR = $PSStyle.Formatting.Error 
}

$KubectlLogLevels = $KubectlStyle.Keys -join '|'
$KubectlLogPattern = "^\[.+($KubectlLogLevels)\]" 
# Uncomment to colorize the whole line:
# $KubectlLogPattern = "^\[.+($KubectlLogLevels)\].*" 

function kubectl { 
    $command = Get-Command kubectl -CommandType Application 
    & $command $args 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace $KubectlLogPattern, { 
            # produce the substitution value
            $fullMatch = $_.Groups[0].Value
            $logLevel  = $_.Groups[1].Value
            $KubectlStyle[$logLevel] + $fullMatch + $PSStyle.Reset 
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Console output]

The colorization code requires [PS 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), but the basic principle of overriding a (native) command could be applied to PS 5.1 too:

- Define a function named like the original command.
- In the function body, get the original command using `Get-Command`. By passing `-CommandType Application`, PowerShell searches only for a native command of the given name, within the paths defined by the `PATH` environment variable. So make sure that the full directory path of `kubectl` is added to the `PATH` variable.
- Call the original command using call operator `&`, forwarding the arguments of the function via the automatic `$args` variable.
- Merge the stdout and stderr streams using redirection operator `2>&1` so both can be processed by `ForEach-Object`.
- Now the **PS 7+** specific code:

  - The `$KubectlStyle` variable is a `Hashtable` that maps each log level to one of the predefined PowerShell formatting codes. Enter `$PSStyle` in the console to see what other values are available. You may even specify RGB values like this: `$PSStyle.Foreground.FromRgb(255,127,255)`.
  - Using the `-replace` operator, we define a regular expression to match the `[...]` substring of the log lines and a script block to dynamically define the replacement value.
  - Within the script block, `$_` is the current match. `$_.Groups[1].Value` is either "INF", "WRN" or "ERR", while `$_.Groups[0].Value` is the value of the full match (the whole `[...]` substring).
  - To produce the substitution value, we look up the style code from the `$KubectlStyle` hashtable, proceed to add the full match and add `$PSStyle.Reset` to reset the style to the default.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you get started, it will only work for those lines that [matches the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/D1UFaw/1). You can add more options to each Key Value, such as `BackgroundColor` etc. This technique uses [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2) to determine the coloring of the lines.

```
$test = @'
[12:00:49 INF] hello
[12:00:49 WRN] world
[12:00:49 ERR] 123
[12:00:49 INF] 123
[12:00:49 WRN] world
[12:00:49 ERR] hello
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$map = @{
    ERR = @{ ForegroundColor = 'Red' }
    WRN = @{ ForegroundColor = 'Yellow' }
    INF = @{ ForegroundColor = 'Green' }
}
[regex] $re = '(?<=^\[[\d:]+\s)(?:{0})' -f ($map.Keys -join '|')

foreach ($line in $test) {
    # get the key we need to use for this line with regex
    # and assign it to `$key`
    if ($key = $re.Match($line).Value) {
        # if the line matched the pattern, get inner hashtable
        $fg = $map[$key]
        # use splatting
        Write-Host @fg $line
        # and go to next line
        continue
    }
    # if the line didn't match the pattern, use default `Write-Host` values
    Write-Host $line
}
```

Comment: I'm loving the indirection for resolving the correct splatting table from `$map` - but it's not super intuitive in-and-of-itself, perhaps add some comments inline?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen agreed, thanks

Comment: thanks I will use it as base for final solution